# MySQL name LIKE '%#attributes.q#%' --- Doesn't return result for an exact match?

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, sql-like

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    customer
WHERE   
fName LIKE '%#attributes.q#%' AND deleted = 'N'
OR 
lName LIKE '%#attributes.q#%' AND deleted = 'N'
```

This works fine for guesses, but if you provide an exact match: "Bill Clinton" fname=bill lname = clinton to the query above you get 0 results? where bill clint gives results.

How can this query be updated to say find LIKE result and EQUAL TO results?

Comment: I can't seem to understand what you are looking for. Is fname='first name' and lname='last name'? Your sample query, the 'explanation' below it and the question in the end don't seem to belong together. Can you please reduce to SQL only and rephrase the question!

Comment: i am not familiar with the "#attributes.q#" notation, but you seem to be supplying the same value for both fName and lName matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell from your question, but I'm guessing your customers table will look something like:

```
id    fName    lName      deleted
---------------------------------
1     John     Doe        N
2     Bill     Clinton    N
3     Fred     Smith      N
4     George   Bush       Y
```

Your query, as you've stated it in your question, will never work, as it will look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE fname LIKE '%Bill Clinton%' AND deleted = 'N'
OR
  lName LIKE '%Bill Clinton%' AND deleted = 'N'
```

There are no records in the table where the fName OR lName fields contain "Bill Clinton"

You would have to massage your #attributes.q# text so it'll generate something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
WHERE ((fName LIKE '%Bill%') OR (fName LIKE '%Clinton%')) AND deleted = 'N'
OR
   ((lName LIKE '%Bill%') etc.....
```

LIKE comparisons are very much like using wildcards in filenames. They won't split up a block of text for you, but will tell you if a chunk of text exists, verbatim, inside another chunk of text.

I think what you need is a [FULLTEXT search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html), which will consider individual words in a query string and return results. Of course, FULLTEXT is only available on MyISAM table types, so if you're using InnoDB or some other type, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - Full-text indexes can be used only with InnoDB or MyISAM tables, and can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.